# Returning subscription result as promise

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code that I would like to use. It is a simple service that returns and array of objects. TS is reporting the following error at the line with `return new Promise...`

`error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'UserPurchasedPlan[]'. Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.`

Below is the code that I have attempted. Working in Angular 5.2 and CLI version 1.6.8.

```
export class LicensesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _paymentService: PaymentService) { }

  purchasedPlans: UserPurchasedPlan[] = [];

  async GetPurchasedPlans(): Promise<UserPurchasedPlan[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const sub = this._paymentService.GetPurchasedPlans().subscribe(
        response => {
          resolve(response);
          sub.unsubscribe();
        },
        err => {
          reject(err);
          sub.unsubscribe();
        }
      );
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GetPurchasedPlans().then(
      plans => {
        this.purchasedPlans = plans;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Likely, `response` is an Object and not an array .. And you need to access response.data or whatever `GetPurchasedPlans` is made of

Comment: hovering response shows: `(parameter) response: UserPurchasedPlan[]` the `GetPurchasedPlans` method is an Observable returning `UserPurchasedPlan[]`

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to just convert the `Observable` from `this._paymentService.GetPurchasedPlans()` to a `Promise` with `toPromise()`?
Then you can change the `ngOnInit()` to:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.GetPurchasedPlans().toPromise().then(
    plans => {
      this.purchasedPlans = plans;
    }
  ).catch((err) => console.log('Error: %s', err));
}
```

whole class:

```
export class LicensesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _paymentService: PaymentService) { }

  purchasedPlans: UserPurchasedPlan[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this._paymentService.GetPurchasedPlans().toPromise().then(
      plans => {
        this.purchasedPlans = plans;
      }
    ).catch((err) => console.log('Error: %s', err));
  }
}
```

Comment: That's super neat!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this instead:

```
async GetPurchasedPlans(): Promise<UserPurchasedPlan[]> {
  return this._paymentService.GetPurchasedPlans()
    .pipe( 
        map((response) => {  // <- Import this map from 'rxjs/operators'
            const mappedResponse: UserPurchasedPlan[] = [] // <- Here you need to map your response to UserPurchasedPlan[]
            return mappedResponse;
        })
    ).ToPromise();
}
```